# SSRS divide total group amount using Tablix

Tags: reporting-services, percentage, ssrs-tablix

I want to use an expression to get the percentage of two rows as per screen shot below.

[Click Here to View Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FLL4.png)

Total Group = Cost / Revenue

[Click here to view the actual value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiuRt.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reference the value of the textbox directly using the `ReportItems` syntax like the following:

```
= ReportItems!TotalRow3.Value / ReportItems!TotalRow1.Value
```

Make sure to replace the `TotalRow` parts with the actual name of the textboxes and this should give you the correct result.

Comment: you may want to watch out for the divide by 0 error. Lots of solutions out there to work around this ssrs niggle!

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for your reply. Apparently, rows are dynamically populated from the database. I have attached the actual generated report from SSRS. Here is my formula: IIF(ReportItems!Header.Value = "Cost",ReportItems!Textbox52.Value,0)/IIF(ReportItems!Header.Value="Revenue",ReportItems!Textbox52.Value,0) Note: ReportItems!Textbox52.Value is the Total Column. Unfortunately, got an #Error display..

Comment: @JP80 Harry brings up a good point -- you should be setting the `False` value to 1, not zero.  Also, is it possible to rewrite this using the values provided from the dataset?  `=SUM(IIF(Fields!Header.Value = "Cost", Fields!Textbox52.Value, 0)) / SUM(IIF(Fields!Header.Value = "Revenue", Fields!Textbox52.Value, 1))`

Comment: @Steve-o169 still not working. Anyway, is it possible to call subreport using expression with parameters?

Comment: @JP80 No, you can't get data from the subreport but you can add the dataset used in the subreport to the outer report and get the same values.